# An irreducible representation of $S_N$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

Let the permutation group $S_N$ acts on the set $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N \}$ in the natural way. This action provides an $N$-dimensional representation of $S_N$.
But it is reducible. Because $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_N $ is an invariant vector.

It is conjected that the $(N-1)$-dimensional complement subspace provides an irredubile representation. I checked it with $N=3,4,5$ simply by calculating the characters.

Does it hold for all $N$?

Comment: Yes, it always holds. It is called the standard representation of $S_N$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here's a nice exercise:

> **Exercise:** Let $G$ act transitively on a finite set $X$. Then the [permutation representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_representation) $\mathbb{C}[X]$ has a $1$-dimensional trivial subspace spanned by $\sum_{x \in X} x$. The orthogonal complement of this subspace is a representation of $G$ which is irreducible iff $G$ acts doubly transitively on $X$.

Besides the action of $S_n$ on $[n] = \{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$, a nice family of doubly transitive group actions is the action of $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ on the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$, which is even $3$-transitive. It follows that the above construction produces an irreducible $q$-dimensional representation of $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.